# Always show login form on checkout page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, login

Currently, in Magento 2 the login form is visible only when I enter an email address, that only if there is an account on the system.

I want to show the login form even if the user doesn't enter his email address.

Comment: which login form is this, the one on top?

Comment: yes. above the address

Comment: Doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is property name "**isPasswordVisible**" in the js file 
**MAGENTO-ROOT/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/form/element/email.js**. You may try to override **email.js** class and set **isPasswordVisible** = true as describe below to always show the password field in the checkout page.

I assume you are using a custom theme name "Company_mytheme"

**step 1)**

Create **requirejs-config.js** under  ***MAGENTO-ROOT/app/design/frontend/Company/mytheme/Magento_Checkout***

**File**: MAGENTO-ROOT/app/design/frontend/Company/mytheme/Magento_Checkout/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {    
        mixins: {            
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/form/element/email': {'Magento_Checkout/js/view/form/element/email-mixin': true},
        },                
    }         
};
```

**step 2:**

Create the mixin js file **email-mixin.js** ***MAGENTO-ROOT/app/design/frontend/Company/mytheme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/form/element/***

**File:** MAGENTO-ROOT/app/design/frontend/Company/mytheme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/form/element/email-mixin.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
define([
    'jquery',
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({
            /**
             * @override
             */                          
             initConfig: function () {
                this._super();
                this.isPasswordVisible = true;                          
                return this;
            }  
        });
    }
});
```

**Step 3:** Refresh Magento cache

```
sudo php bin/magento c:f
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your solution worked.

Comment: It’s my pleasure.